# How to calculate $\iiint_E z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

$$\iiint_E z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz\,,$$ where $E$ is bounded by $y=\sqrt{4x-x^2}$ and $y=0, z=0,z =4$.

How can I calculate this? I found $E$ just like a half cylinder. Then I found $$0\leqq x\leqq4, 0\leqq z\leqq4, 0\leqq y\leqq\sqrt{4x-x^2}$$

But I don't know whether it is correct. What is the value of it?

Comment: do you know about cylindrical polar variables? with a quick look i think they will be helpful

Comment: Try the change of variables $u=x+2$ and convert to cylindrical coordinates,.

Comment: Can I just use $x=2+rcos(\theta)$, $y=rsin(\theta)$? But it seems hard to calculate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$\iiint_E z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz
= \int_0^4 zdz\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{4\cos\theta} r^2drd\theta
=\frac{1024}9
$$